# Prevent click events on links but allow touch events

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, cordova, hammer.js

Im using hammer.js for gestures in a html5 app, also on phonegap.

I want to prevent normal clicks of links to go to the link, but I want t tap event to let the link pass. Im trying this sofar, but it prevents both events, I guess the click events comes first

```
$(document).hammer().on("tap click", "a", function(e){
    if e.type == "click"
        return false
}
```

I want to do this because I have a hold event, and after the hold is done over a link, the link is fired. I dont want this to happen..

Comment: It seems the click/touch events is triggered before the hold event, as the hold event comes form the start of a click/touch event. So this is somewhat of a challange

Comment: Can you try preventDefault on tap click, and then perform your tap action?

Comment: If you do that then you cant tap/trigger the links anymore

Answer (score 0):

listen for

```
$(document).on('touchend',function(e){
    /*
        you code here
    */

    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation()
});
```